# Isoperimetric profile with obstacle

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, isoperimetric-problems

Fix two open smooth bounded domains $\Omega_-$ and $\Omega_+$ with $\overline{\Omega}_-\subset \Omega_+$ in a complete Riemannian manifold  ($\mathbb{R}^n$ is already interesting to me).

I was wondering if there is any literature on the following question: For $V\in (0, |\Omega_+|-|\Omega_-|)$ let
$$
P_{min}(V)=\min\{ |\partial^* E|: \Omega_-\subset E\subset \Omega_+, |E\backslash \Omega_-|=V\}
$$
where here $E$ is a set of finite perimeter.  That is we are trying to find the region containing $\Omega_-$ and contained in $\Omega_+$ with that encloses a fixed amount of volume (namely $V+|\Omega_-|$) and has least area.

Standard compactness arguments for sets of finite perimeter should give a minimizer $E_{min}(V)$ with $|\partial^* E_{min}(V)|=P_{min}(V)$ that has constant mean curvature (in a weak sense) in $\Omega_+\backslash \overline{\Omega}_-$.  I would also expect something like smoothness for the (reduced) boundary of this minimizer away from a codimension 7 singular set in this set. I would also expect something like free boundary behavior at $\partial \Omega_-\cup \partial \Omega_+$.

I'm particularly interested in what happens as $V\to 0$.  I would expect that (perhaps under some additional geometric conditions on $\Omega_-$) that the minimizers should like like little ``bumps" on $\Omega_-$ when $V$ is below some critical value.

This seems like a fairly natural problem to study, but haven't been able to find anything on it from a cursory search of the literature.

Comment: Did you ever find any information about this? Have you worked on this since?

Comment: I ended up finding a different and simpler to the actual problem I was interested in so didn't pursue this further.

Comment: Are you willing to (broadly) describe the context in which this arose? I'm just curious - no big deal if you'd rather not. By the way, I think the regularity part is covered in a paper by Gonzalez, Massari, Tamanini. On the regularity of boundaries of sets minimizing perimeter with a volume constraint. Indiana University Mathematics Journal, 1983, Vol. 32, No. 1, pp. 25-37.

Comment: It's somewhat technical, but essentially had to do with trying to understand/adapt this https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3126 paper of Morgan and Ros to a different setting.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation!